# Email sent Twice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

for some reason whenever I send I email via my form it double sends me the email with the attachment. but the attachmant dont work (filesize: 0) at all on the reapeted email.

I think its somthing in my aspx.vb code.

```
'Add the namespace for the email-related classes
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class SendAttachment
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        'Make sure a file has been uploaded
        If AttachmentFile.PostedFile.ContentLength > 100000 Then
            'display error file size should be less than 100kb
        End If
        '!!! UPDATE THIS VALUE TO YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS
        Const ToAddress As String = "pelleg@shakuff.co.il"
        Dim textMsg as String
        textMsg = "התנסת בפועל בעבודת ניהול ביצוע בתשתיות בינעירוניות בקנה מידה גדול" & (vbCrLf)  & q1.text & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "רמת ההכרות שלך עם גורמים סטאטוריים, ממשלתיים והרשויות" & (vbCrLf) & q2.text & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "הניסיון שלך בניהול פרויקט ביצוע בתחום התשתיות הבינעירוניות" & (vbCrLf) &q3.text & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "ממליצים" & (vbCrLf) & c1.text & (Space(5)) & c2.text & (Space(5)) & c3.text & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "מעוניין בהצעות נוספות" & (vbCrLf) & q4.text & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "הניסיון שלך בתחום תשתיות הכבישים ועבודה מול מעצ " & (vbCrLf) & q5.text & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "פרטים אישיים" & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "שם מלא" & (vbCrLf) & pi1.text & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "כתובת מייל" & (vbCrLf) & UsersEmail.Text & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "טלפון" & (vbCrLf) & pi2.text & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) &"שעות נוחות" & (vbCrLf) & pi3.text & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "הערות" & (vbCrLf) & body.text
 '
        '(1) Create the MailMessage instance
        Dim mm As New MailMessage(UsersEmail.Text, ToAddress)

        '(2) Assign the MailMessage's properties
        mm.Subject = pi1.text &  "-" & "JB-16"
        mm.Body = textMsg

        mm.IsBodyHtml = false

        'Attach the file
        mm.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(AttachmentFile.PostedFile.InputStream, AttachmentFile.FileName))
        mm.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(AttachmentFile2.PostedFile.InputStream, AttachmentFile2.FileName))

        '(3) Create the SmtpClient object
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient

        '(4) Send the MailMessage (will use the Web.config settings)
        smtp.Send(mm)

        'Show the EmailSentForm Panel and hide the EmailForm Panel
        EmailSentForm.Visible = True
        EmailForm.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            'On the first page load, hide the EmailSentForm Panel
            EmailSentForm.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

any ideas?

Comment: Are you double clicking the button?

Comment: Did you try debugging the application with breakpoints and see whats hapening?

Comment: Im not double clicking.
Shoban, I dont know what you mean.

Comment: @Shoban is asking if you debugged through the application. If you don't know what that means, I suggest you start learning. It is a basic skill for a programmer.

Comment: reiterating @Oded http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have AutoWireUpEvent=true in your .aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the click handler twice?  I see you have "Handles btnSubmit.Click" on the function definition.  Are you assigning the onClick event somwehere else to also use that function?

That is the most common cause of a button click event firing twice.